# stacked bar plot with ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a stacked bar plot with the following dataframe:

```
 totalleft
        1S 2S 3S 4S 12S 25S      tests
A-000   5  0 10 10   0  NA       A-000
A-001  10  8 10 NA  NA  NA       A-001
A-002   5  3 10 10  10  NA       A-002
A-003   2  0 10  9   0  10       A-003
A-004   5  4 10 10  10  NA       A-004
A-005   5  3 10 10  10  NA       A-005
A-006   8  7 NA 10  10  NA       A-006
A-009   9 10 NA NA  10  10       A-009
A-015  NA  1 NA NA  NA  NA       A-015
A-016  NA  0 10 NA   6   9       A-016
A-017  NA  0 NA NA   4  NA       A-017
A-020  NA  1 NA NA  NA  NA       A-020
A-025  NA  0 NA NA   0  NA       A-025
A-025a NA  0 NA NA  10  NA      A-025a
A-026  NA  9 10 NA   9   9       A-026
A-027  NA  0 10 NA   2   9       A-027
A-028  NA  0 NA NA   1  NA       A-028
A-030  NA  7 NA NA   8   8       A-030
B-000     0  0  7  8   0   0     B-000
B-056     4  0  9 NA   0   5     B-056
B-076     9  9 NA NA  10  10     B-076
B-099     6  5 10 NA   5   9     B-099
B-102     7  0 NA NA   0  10     B-102
B-105    NA  6 NA NA  NA   6     B-105
B-119     7  8 10 10  NA  NA     B-119
```

However, most of the documentation involves plotting against two factors:  one for splitting up the bars along the X axis and the other for dividing up each bar.  My questions is how split up the X axis by the factor test and then divide up each bar by the corresponding rows (i.e. `1S,2S,3S,4S,12,25S`).

So, the first bar would be a bar for `A-000`, and 20% of the it would be one color (for the `1S`, 5/(5+10+10)) and the second 40% would be another color (`3S`, 10/(5+10+10)) and the final 40% would be a another color (`4S`, 10/(5+10+10))

I'm using this command as a reference:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill=cut)) + geom_bar()
```

from this website:
http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_bar.html#

Comment: You need to munge the data to make it ggplot friendly. have a look at ?melt from the reshape2 package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need to reshape the data.
You want a stacked barplot, so you will need to tell ggplot about variables 1S, 2S ...
and tests.

```
#let's melt the data
#library(reshape2)
data.plot.m <-melt(data.plot, id.vars = "tests") #I stored your data in data.plot
data.plot.m$variable <-gsub("X","",data.plot.m$variable) 
#as R doesn't like variable names beginning with numbers,
#it adds an 'X' automatically when
#we load the data with read.table so we remove this from melted data

#now we plot the data
ggplot(data.plot.m,aes(y = value,x = variable,fill = tests)) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]
You will notice the order of the plots are different.
We will need to reorder your variable:

```
data.plot.m$variable <- factor(data.plot.m$variable, levels = unique(data.plot.m$variable))
#now plot again
ggplot(data.plot.m,aes(y = value,x = variable,fill = tests))+
geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

I just realized you wanted this instead

```
ggplot(data.plot.m,aes(y=value,x=tests,fill=variable))+geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

and with the x-axis tick labels rotated

```
ggplot(data.plot.m,aes(y=value,x=tests,fill=variable))+geom_bar(stat="identity") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90))
```

[image]
Note how I switched x and fill

Comment: Ahh, yes, this is excellent.  One thing though...Can we put the test names on the X axis and the 1S, 2S, etc. as the colors?

Answer (score 2):

This seems like what you wanted??

[image]

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

gg <- melt(totalleft,id="tests")
ggplot(gg) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=tests, y=value, fill=variable), stat="identity")+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=-90, vjust=.2, hjust=0))
```

`melt(...)` converts your data frame from "wide" format (groups in different columns) to "long" format (all the values in one column (called `value`), and groups distinguished by a separate column (called `variable`).